# HTML Banners transfer data

Tags: html

I'm looking for method of transferring user entered data from a banner Advertisement to a landing page as if it was entered from the landing page.

The banner is for a domain registrar company and has one field to enter a domain. When submitted, the banner links to the landing page and checks the availability of the domain name that was entered in the banner.

Currently have flash banners that do it, but need a non-flash option.

Any ideas? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site hosting the banner would have to allow html or embedded iframes for your content. If you can use either of these options then you may be able to use the following code

```
<form method="get" action="URL_TO_POST_DATA_TO">

<input type="text" value="enter a domain" name="domain" />
<input type="submit" value="go" />

</form>
```

when the user hits submit you will end up on URL_TO_POST_DATA_TO?domain=VALUE_ENTERED